# How to get all media tracks from chromecast receiver

Tags: android, chromecast

We have a custom receiver that is using an HLS stream with segmented webvtts. Is there a way on Android to obtain the text tracks that were loaded on the receiver?

It seems that

```
MediaInfo#getMediaTracks
```

only returns tracks that were provided to the receiver through the load method.

Is using a custom channel the only way to do this? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#add_a_custom_channel

Comment: Try to check this [`loadTracksInfo`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#loadTracksInfo) if it can help you. It allows you to load tracks if the load is still ongoing. This method is useful if the application wants to override onLoad, but still wants to use the default behavior for tracks handling. For example, this can be useful if the application has to override onLoad to support HLS, but it is using vtt closed captions. Note that if the mediaManager is no longer in the loading state, the request will be ignored.

Comment: Overriding this method allows me to select the correct track on receiver. But my question was how to I obtain the available tracks from a client app?